# Changes to Azure Load balancer not working

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, azure-public-ip

I created an Azure Load Balancer with 2 front ends, two backend pools and two load balancing rules.

Then I have a script that swaps the pools between the load balancing rules. 
I then call Set-AzureRmLoadBalancer to update the load balancer configuration.

I can see the swap taking effect when I query using Get-AzureRmLoadBalancer, and also see it in the Azure Portal, but the load balancer continues to behave as if there was no changes to its configuration.

Am I missing something? Is there a separate command I need to call to force the load balancer to use the new configuration?

Answer (score 0):

That should not be necessary if the Set command succeeded. Please reach out to support to investigate.